# calculation of average ROC in IMageNet paper?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, roc

The IMageNEt paper [Image Net.](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Li_Jia_Li/publication/221361415_ImageNet_a_Large-Scale_Hierarchical_Image_Database/links/00b495388120dbc339000000/ImageNet-a-Large-Scale-Hierarchical-Image-Database.pdf) presents the Average ROC curve for the 16 classes in the imagenet data, visit image figure. 8 in the paper. what is the known function to compute this ROC plot. As ROC plot is for a binary classification problem. Is this average ROC plot made in the picture average of ROC's for all the 16 categories. Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: My understanding is that they treat each category (e.g. elk) as binary, for which you can obtain false positive and true positive rates, as well as an ROC curve. Then they average the ROC curves.

Comment: For example taking only one class into account, and taking its probabilities to plot ROC curve. In the end averaging all the ROC plots to form a ROC for the whole.I am trying to do it for a image classification problem but the ROC(AUC) that I am getting is almost similar for all the classifiers.@YuvalHarpaz

Comment: Is it same as applying micro average.http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-py